# Beer lambert law ratio

Tags: voltage-measurement, photodiode

I once read an article (source : http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7561271/ ) about measure absorbance using photodiode
The formula used is :

\$A= -\log{\frac{I}{Io}} = - \log \left(\frac{V_{sample}-{V_{zero}}}{V_{solvent}-V_{zero}}\right) \$

Where Io and I are incident light intensity and transmitted light intensity

ܸVsample and Vsolvent is voltage when the light transmits a sample and solvent respectively . Vzero is the voltage at
zero light

I understand why they used Vsample - Vzero , but the substraction Vsolvent - Vzero seems to be wrong , this is true only if the solvent does not absorb the light , but in fact even water absorb light . So what did i miss here?

Comment: I don't understand why its only true if the solvent doesn't absorb light.  You're measuring the attenuation of light transmission due to the solute.

Comment: Absorbance  applies only at the matched wavelengths predicted, not all wavelengths. Use a Bragg diffractor

Comment: that cheap one in article uses  RGB when RYGtGaBV  different LEDs is better for measuring absorption  where Gt and Ga are true and aqua green. One can also add IR and UV

Answer (score 1):

Most photoreceptors have a dark current, which will cause a voltage at the output of an amplifier.  The equation removes this effect from the numerator and from the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Received amplitude is < 1 thus -log of ratio <1 is a positive value indicating absorption of  sample(+solvent)/solvent.

PD with TIA is much more accurate than a PhotoTransistor due to huge variance of hFE.  So calibration is critical for every unit and temperature stability etc.

[image]